# node.js can not make post request from ionic 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic4

I am trying to make a post request from ionic 4. But can't read data sent with post method (`req.body.value`) in node.js.

Getting following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined

Here is my code

ionic service

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ Content-Type': 'application/json })
  };


    captureOrder (order): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.url + 'ordersapi', order, this.httpOptions)
      }
```

ionic client page

```
var options = {
      amount : this.total,  
      currency: "INR",
      payment_capture: '1'
    };
    console.log(options);

    this.ordersapiService.captureOrder(options).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
    })
```

sent body to server

```
{amount: 91, currency: "INR", payment_capture: "1"}
amount: 91
currency: "INR"
payment_capture: "1"
```

node js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Razorpay = require('razorpay');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const router = express.Router();
app.use('/', router);

router.post('/ordersapi', function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.amount) // getting as undefined
})
```

My express version is 4.16.1. What is going wrong in the above example? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: please post the client side code for the request also.

Comment: I just edited question

Comment: in your client page does console.log(options) returns proper value of amount or returns undefined?

Comment: It returns proper values

Comment: I am not sure if that is the problem but have you tried adding `Content-Type: application/json` header

Comment: if you are sending json data then you will have to set the `ontent-Type: application/json` header otherwise the body will be empty.

Comment: I have edited the question. Set header as Content-Type: application/json. But still can't access the value at node.js

Comment: Have you observed the network request to make sure the body is correctly sent? (using firefox dev tools for example) Have you paused in a debugger in the node service, to see what the incoming `req` object looks like? Eg: is body containing anything

Comment: Hii. I just updated sent body to server